# Python multiprocessing without printing started and stopped?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

When I start or stop a process, there is a line in stdout like `<Process(Process-1, started)>`. But I do not want to print out this line, how can I prevent this?

My code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def spawn(f):
    def func(pipe, param):
        pipe.send(f(param))
        pipe.close()
    return func


def parallel_map(func, params, num_of_processes=None):
    num_of_processes = mp.cpu_count() if not num_of_processes else num_of_processes
    pipes = [mp.Pipe() for i in range(num_of_processes)]
    result = []
    for step in xrange(0, len(params), num_of_processes):
        tmp_nop = num_of_processes if step + num_of_processes <= len(params) else len(params) - step
        processes = [mp.Process(target=spawn(func), args=(pipes[i][1], params[step + i]))
                     for i in range(tmp_nop)]
        for process in processes:
            process.start()
        for process in processes:
            print process
            process.join()
        result = result + [p.recv() for (p, c) in pipes[:tmp_nop]]
    return result
```

Comment: That line is coming because you're printing process.

Comment: If you don't want it, why are you printing it with `print process`?

Comment: maybe he wanted process name or number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you have included in your code a line `print process` that prints out exactly what you wanted it not to print. Remove that line and all should be well.